# VBA - SQL query with dates as variable on Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, variables

I am performing in VBA an SQL query selecting per date. Everything is working until I specify the dates, as the code below:

```
conn.Open dbConnectStr

StartDate = "01/01/2015"

SQL_String = "SELECT * FROM database " & _
             "WHERE date BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('31/12/2016','dd/mm/yyyy')"

recset.Close
conn.Close
```

But, when I put in a variable instead of dates I obtain an error `multiple-step operation completed with one or more errors. Check each status values.`

```
conn.Open dbConnectStr

StartDate = "01/01/2015"
EndDate = "31/12/2016"

SQL_String = "SELECT * FROM database " & _
             "WHERE date BETWEEN to_date('" & StartDate & "','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('" & EndDate & "','dd/mm/yyyy')"

recset.Close
conn.Close
```

Anybody could suggest how to proceed?

Comment: This is not a complete code. Where are you `Dim` statements? Where do you actually execute the `SQL_String`? Please be more complete. No need to share anything proprietary, just be as complete as possible

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine(SQL_String)` and see if the sql is correct

Comment: If you have new info, edit your question instead of posting false answers. Thank you.