# Make date variable in a oracle query using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle, date

first I'm sorry for the poor english but I'll try my best.

I have an oracle query running in a VBA macro and I need to set the date in the sql select as a variable that relates to a sheet cell, I already managed to make the sql consult work.

I would really appreciate some help with this, I'm really stuck, down goes the working code.

```
Private Sub cmdConexaoBD_Click()

Dim sql As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer

'define a conexão com o banco de dados
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

cn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=database;uid=username;pwd=password;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sql = "SELECT NUMOS,MIN(DTINICIOOS),MAX(DTFIMOS),MAX(DTFIMOS)-MIN(DTINICIOOS) FROM PCMOVENDPEND WHERE DATA >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) GROUP BY NUMOS"

rs.Open sql, cn

Range("A1").Value = "OS"
Range("B1").Value = "DT"
Range("C1").Value = "DT"
Range("D1").Value = "TEMPO"

i = 1

If Not rs.EOF Then

Do While Not rs.EOF

Range("A" & i + 1).Value = rs(0)
Range("B" & i + 1).Value = rs(1)
Range("C" & i + 1).Value = rs(2)
Range("D" & i + 1).Value = rs(3)
rs.MoveNext
i = i + 1

Loop

End If

cn.Close

End Sub
```

Where is written `WHERE DATA >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)` "DATA" actually is date (it's in portuguese), I want to set the date as a variable referring to a sheet cell, so I can change it in the spreadsheet and import the data of such date without changing the code.

I hope that I made myself clear, Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to show data type and sysdate value type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118844/vba-sql-query-with-dates-as-variable-on-oracle-db

Comment: Saying *"DATA" actually is date (it's in portuguese)* is a contradiction in self. A `DATE` values does not have any format or language, it is stored as internal byte value. What you see is the (default) **display** format/language. So what is the data type of column `DATA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim dt

dt = format(Range("F1").Value,"mm/dd/yyyy")  'your date is in F1

sql = " SELECT NUMOS,MIN(DTINICIOOS),MAX(DTFIMOS),MAX(DTFIMOS)-MIN(DTINICIOOS) " & _
      " FROM PCMOVENDPEND " & _ 
      " WHERE DATA >= to_date('" & dt & "','mm/dd/yyyy') GROUP BY NUMOS "
```

Comment: GREAT
Actually I managed to make the SQL code as a variable referring to a sheet cell and put the sql query there, but I wasn't satisfied, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use bind variables, so you need something like this:

```
Set dbADOCommand = New ADODB.Command 
Set dbADOParameter = New ADODB.Parameter 

sql = "SELECT NUMOS,MIN(DTINICIOOS),MAX(DTFIMOS),MAX(DTFIMOS)-MIN(DTINICIOOS) FROM PCMOVENDPEND WHERE DATA >= :bindDate GROUP BY NUMOS"

dbADOCommand.CommandText = sql
dbADOCommand.CommandType = adCmdText 
dbADOCommand.NamedParameters = true 
dbADOCommand.Prepared = true 


Set dbADOParameter = dbADOCommand.CreateParameter("bindDate", _ 
                                                  ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDBDate, _ 
                                                  ADODB.adParamInput, _ 
                                                  8, _ 
                                                  "2020-01-01")
dbADOCommand.Parameters.Append dbADOParameter 

Set dbADORecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
Set dbADORecordSet = dbADOCommand.Execute
```